# React.js CRUD using DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, reactjs

What is the best way to perform add, edit and delete row functions in Reactjs using DataTables?

I found some examples of React/datatables online but all of them just display the contents. The problem that I'm having is the datatable does not get updated whenever I add a row for example using React. I understand that's because of React's virtual DOM. Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post an example jsfiddle to show what you are talking about